# Get velocity template from database in Springboot

Tags: database, spring-boot, velocity

I have to get velocity templates from database in Spring boot and Spring data project.I have not tried any code yet as I am new to all technologies(Velocity, Spring boot and data) and not finding anything on google. Does anybody tried here to get template from db, please suggest me some links or anything else which i can refer?

Update: I have binding classes in db (in grails) and I have to access process method from java .In db class is ,
class bindingSubject {
    def log
    def process = { pub,listForMail ->

```
    def mapBinding = [:]
    def fund
    def perimeters = pub.sub.entities
    perimeters.each(){ entity ->
         if (fu == null){
            if (entity instanceof S)
                fu = entity.fu
            if (entity instanceof Fund)
                fu = fu
         }
    }mapBinding.entity = fu.name                                             return mapBinding
}
```

}
  and java code written to

-> Load script

```
 mapScriptClass = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            if (script != null) {
                if (mapScriptClass.get(name) == null) {

                    GroovyCodeSource groovySource = new GroovyCodeSource(script,name,"");
                    GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());

                    // Load string as Groovy script class.
                    Class scriptClass = classLoader.parseClass(groovySource);

                    try {
                        Object classInstance  =  scriptClass.newInstance();

                        ApplicationContext ctx = (ApplicationContext)ServletContextHolder
                                .getServletContext().getAttribute(ApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT);

                        ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(classInstance, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_NAME, false);
                        mapScriptClass.put(name, classInstance);
                        return classInstance;
```

To call process method from db(in grails this works , how to do it in java?)

```
 Object scriptClass = loadScriptService.getScriptClass("scriptBindingSubject"+templateMail.getId(),
                                templateMail.getScriptBindingSubject());
                        if (scriptClass != null) {
                            try{
                                bindingSubject = scriptClass.process(pub,subMail); 
                            }
```

now i am not sure how to call process method from java(to db) to bind properties

Thanks.

Comment: There is sample example https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-velocity

Comment: Why do you want to store our templates in a database? I'd be a lot simpler if they were bundled directly in your app

Comment: HI Andy, actually its a grails project which has templates saved in html format in db and now i have to access some templates in java applications   , in grails SimpleTemplateEngine is being used with GroovyClassLoader to bind variables so in java I have to use something similar , any other substitute do u have other than velocity which can talk with GroovyClassLoader smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

As you write, the templates are stored in the database.

So you need to read them (using JDBC or JPA) and depending on how they are stored, you will get a String, char[] or byte[].

You can convert all of them into a [java.io.Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html?is-external=true) like 
[CharArrayReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/CharArrayReader.html), [StringReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html),
how this can be done for a byte[] you can see in this [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/java-convert-byte-array-to-reader)

[SimpleTemplateEngine](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/SimpleTemplateEngine.html) has a method

```
createTemplate(Reader reader)
```

that finally creates the template for the reader.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thanks for info. I have binding classes in database (updated in question) in grails and i have to access process method from java is it possible? plz lemme know

Comment: Hi all, this thread has started with different intetion with keeping velocity in mind and it has gone into a different direction. I will post seoarate thread for that..Thanks all